# If 'float'<= INT_MAX is true, then why (int)'float' may trigger undefined behavior?

Tags: c, type-conversion, undefined-behavior, c11, c17

Sample code (t0.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define F 2147483600.0f

int main(void)
{
        printf("F            %f\n", F);
        printf("INT_MAX      %d\n", INT_MAX);
        printf("F <= INT_MAX %d\n", F <= INT_MAX);
        if      ( F <= INT_MAX )
        {
                printf("(int)F       %d\n", (int)F);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t0.c && ./a.exe
F            2147483648.000000
INT_MAX      2147483647
F <= INT_MAX 1
(int)F       2147483647

$ clang t0.c && ./a.exe
F            2147483648.000000
INT_MAX      2147483647
F <= INT_MAX 1
(int)F       0
```

Questions:

1. If `F` is printed as `2147483648.000000`, then why `F <= INT_MAX` is true?
2. What is the correct way to avoid UB here?

UPD. Solution:

```
if      ( lrintf(F) <= INT_MAX )
{
        printf("(int)F       %d\n", (int)F);
}
```

UPD2. Better solution:

```
if      ( F <= nextafter(((float)INT_MAX) + 1.0f, -INFINITY) )
{
        printf("(int)F       %d\n", (int)F);
}
```

Comment: `float` cannot hold enough significance.

Comment: Can you add `printf("INT_MAX as float %f\n", (float)INT_MAX);`? If it prints `2147483648`, you have the answer why the `if` is true.

Comment: Remember that the limited precision of type `float` (or any noninfinite floating-point type) can apply to the left of the decimal point as well as the right. There is no such `float` number as 2147483600.  The nearest representable `float` value is 2147483648.

Comment: With `if  ( F <= nextafter(((float)INT_MAX) + 1.0f, -INFINITY) )`, was `nextafterf()` intended, or are you suggesting a `double` function?  IAC, your solutions do not belong in the question, but as a post of your own answer where they can be properly rated.

Comment: `if  ( lrintf(F) <= INT_MAX )` is the wrong when `(float) INT_MAX` is exact.  e.g. 16-bit `int`, 64-bit `float`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing a value of type `int` with a value of type `float`.  The operands of the `<=` operator need to first be converted to a common type to evaluate the comparison.

This falls under the **usual arithmetic conversions**.  In this case, the value of type `int` is converted to type `float`.  And because the value in question (2147483647)  cannot be represented exactly as a `float`, it results in the closest representable value, in this case 2147483648.  This matches what the constant represented by the macro `F` converts to, so the comparison is true.

Regarding the cast of `F` to type `int`, because the integer part of `F` is outside the range of an `int`, this triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 6.3.1.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) dictates how these conversions from integer to floating point and from floating point to integer are performed:

> *1* When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the  fractional  part  is  discarded
> (i.e.,  the  value  is  truncated  toward  zero). **If  the  value  of
> the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the
> behavior is undefined.**
>
> *2* When  a  value  of  integer  type  is  converted  to  a  real  floating  type,  if  the  value  being converted can be represented
> exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. **If the value being
> converted  is  in  the  range  of  values  that  can  be  represented
> but  cannot  be  represented exactly, the result is either the nearest
> higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an
> implementation-defined manner.** If the value being converted is
> outside the range of values  that  can  be  represented,  the
> behavior  is  undefined. Results  of  some  implicit conversions  may
> be  represented  in  greater  range  and  precision  than  that
> required  by  the new type (see 6.3.1.8 and 6.8.6.4)

And section 6.3.1.8p1 dictates how the usual arithmetic conversions are performed:

> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
> to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  corresponding  real  type  of  either  operand
> is `double`, the  other operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `double`.
>
> **Otherwise,  if  the  corresponding  real  type  of  either  operand
> is `float`, the  other operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float`.**

As for how to avoid undefined behavior in this case, if the constant `F` has no suffix i.e. `2147483600.0` then it has type `double`.  This type can represent exactly any 32 bit integer value, so the given value is not rounded and can be stored in an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I forgot that in `int` is converted to `float` in `<=`. The solution is to use `lrintf()`: `if (lrintf(F) <= INT_MAX)`.

Comment: dbush, using a `double` may nearly solve the `int/float` issue, (`F <= 2147483647.0` is the wrong test, should be `F < 2147483648.0` or still as `float` math `F < 2147483648.0f`)  but begs the solution for a `long long/double` one.  We can take advantage `some_integer_type_MAX` is a is a [mersine number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) to form an [exact FP limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68837262/2410359) and then not need to rely on wider types.

Comment: @pmor `lrintf(F) <= INT_MAX` is not the best as it is not true with values in the [INT_MAX + 0.5 .... INT_MAX + 1.0) range.

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of your problem is the implicit conversion from the `INT_MAX` literal to a `float` value, when doing the `F <= INT_MAX` comparisons. The `float` data type simply does not have enough precision to properly store the `2147483647` value, and (it so happens), the value of `2147483648` is stored, instead<sup>†.</sup>

The clang-cl compiler warns about this:

> warning : implicit conversion from 'int' to 'float' changes value from
> 2147483647 to 2147483648 [-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion]

And, you can confirm this yourself by adding the following line to your code:

```c
printf("(float)IMAX  %f\n", (float)INT_MAX);
```

That line displays `(float)IMAX  2147483648.000000` on my system (Windows 10, 64-bit, clang-cl in Visual Studio 2019).

---

† The *actual* value stored in the `float` in such cases is implementation-defined, as pointed out in [the excellent answer by dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68832230/10871073).

Answer (score 1):

> If F is printed as 2147483648.000000, then why F <= INT_MAX is true?

> If 'float'<= INT_MAX is true, then why (int)'float' may trigger undefined behavior?

`#define F 2147483600.0f ... if ( F <= INT_MAX )` is an insufficient test as it is imprecise.    The conversion of `INT_MAX` to `float` typically suffers rounding.

---

> What is the correct way to avoid UB here?

To test if a `float` is convertible to a `int` without a problem, first review the spec:

> When a finite value of standard floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined. C17dr

This means floating point values like [-2,147,483,648.999... to 2,147,483,647.999...] are acceptable `float` - or with extended math: `(INT_MIN - 1 to INT_MAX + 1)`.  Note [] v. ().

There is no need for wider types.

Code needs to compare the range, as `float`, precisely.
`(INT_MAX/2 + 1) * 2.0f` is exact as `INT_MAX` is a [Mersenne Number](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html).  <sup>*1</sup>

```
// Form INT_MAX_PLUS1 as a float
#define F_INT_MAX_PLUS1 ((INT_MAX/2 + 1) * 2.0f)

// With 2's complement, INT_MIN is exact as a float.

if (some_float < F_INT_MAX_PLUS1 && (some_float - INT_MIN) > -1.0f)) {
  int i = (int) some_float; // no problem
} else {
  puts("Conversion problem");
}
```

Tip: form the test like above to also catch `some_float` as not-a-number.

---

<sup>*1</sup> `some_int_MAX` may be a problem with `UINT128_MAX` or more due to limited `float` exponent range.