# How to automatically select between %f and %a w/o losing precision?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, precision, c11

Sample code:

```
void print_f( float f )
{
   ...
}

int main( void )
{
    print_f( 1.0f );      // prints 1.0
    print_f( 29.0f );     // prints 29.0
    print_f( 29.13f );    // prints 0x1.d2147ap+4
    print_f( 256.0f );    // prints 256.0
    print_f( 256.1f );    // prints 0x1.00199ap+8
    // and so on
    return 0;
}
```

I.e. if the floating constant cannot be printed precisely using `%f`, then `%a` is used.

Question: what is the condition for "the floating constant cannot be printed precisely using `%f`"?

Comment: I would say you never want to switch dynamically between `%f` and `%a`.  If you want human-readable, use `%f`.  If you want machine readable with perfect repeatability, use `%a`.  What consumer won't mind this incompatible back-and-forth between the two?

Comment: Can't be done.  The constant in code is converted to a representable value at compile time.

Comment: This seems to reduce to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68835588/how-to-determine-w-o-conversions-that-a-given-floating-constant-can-be-represent).  If the compiler can't make the determination, then runtime is definitely much too late as the actual token from the source code is no longer available.

Comment: @dbush To my knowledge, some representable values can be printed precisely unsing `%f`, some cannot. The idea is to use `%a` for "cannot" case.

Comment: @pmor What I'm saying is that distinction disappears once the code is compiled.

Comment: @pmor You have to be careful what you mean by "representable values" and "printed precisely".  Many values cannot be represented precisely.  Once a value has been stored in a `float` or `double`, it is also problematic to print it precisely.

Comment: @NateEldredge As as understand: the floating constant cannot represented, however, the variable holding the nearest representable FP value can be precisely printed using `%f`. This question is not about "can / cannot represented", but about "keeping the absolute precision while automatically switching between %f and %a".

Comment: However, for any given floating-point type (e.g. `float` or `double`), I believe you can devise a `printf` precision such that the printed value, even if imprecise, will lead to the same value on the other end if a receiver uses `atof` or `strtod` or `scanf("%f")` to read it back in.  The advantage of `%a` is it makes it *easier* to achieve end-to-end lossless transmission, without printfing possibly-unnecessary extra digits — but I believe you can also achieve end-to-end lossless transmission with `%e` or `%g`.  (Probably not `%f`, though, or at least not without wasting tons of space.)

Comment: Auto selecting between `%f` and `%a` is unlikely to be useful. A number like 1.25f is precise when printed with `%f`, yet 1.225f is not. 16777218.0f is, 16777219.0f is not. So the correct choice is to always use `%a`, or use some ridiculous precision with `%f`, like `%.70f`.

Comment: *To my knowledge, some representable values can be printed precisely using %f, some cannot.* False.  Every `float` and `double` value can be printed perfectly precisely, if you're willing to use enough digits.  (Although it might take 105 digits, even for a `float`.)  But there are plenty of real numbers, and plenty of decimal fractions, that cannot be represented precisely as a `float` or `double`.

Comment: So what would you want for `1.9999999999999999999999999997f`?  The actual number cannot be represented exactly as `float`, but the nearest representable value is `2.0` whose exact value will be printed by the `%f` format specifier.

Comment: @user3386109 Even `%70f` won't always be enough.  But I believe `%10e` or `%10g` probably would be for a float, and 15-20 digits for a `double`.

Comment: @SteveSummit You are correct that `%e` or `%g` is a better choice (to deal with numbers less than 1). But 10 digits is nowhere near enough. For example, the number 1.225000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625f, is precisely representable as a `float`.

Comment: @SteveSummit _if you're willing to use enough digits_: I was talking about plain `%f`. C11: if the precision is missing, it is taken as 6.

Comment: @NateEldredge _what would you want for 1.9999999999999999999999999997f_: yes, the nearest representable value is 2.0 whose exact value will be printed by the %f format specifier. Hence, `2.0`.

Comment: @user3386109 I understand about numbers like 1.225000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625.  But if you print that guy out using, say, `%.6f`, and then convert the resulting string back to a `float`, under a good-quality implementation you will get precisely the same `float` value.

Comment: @SteveSummit And therein lies the reason not to do what OP is attempting to do. Different implementations may have subtly different behaviors, and I believe they are within their rights under the specification to do so.

Comment: So you're asking whether a given `float` value would have its represented value printed exactly with a given number `n` of decimal places to `%f`, or the default `n=6`?  (Not merely that the string printed out would be converted back to the same `float` value.)  The numbers represented by binary floating-point are [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), and a dyadic rational can be printed exactly with `n` decimal places if and only if it is an integer multiple of `2^(-n)`.  Which you can check by simple computations with the significand and exponent.

Comment: Update the question to explicit state the criterion for the selection. For example: (a) If x is the value in `float f`, and `%f` produces a numeral that is exactly x, use `%f`, otherwise use `%a`. (b) If x is the value in `float f`, and `%f` produces a numeral that, when converted to IEEE-754 binary32 (“single”) with correct rounding using round-to-nearest mode, use `%f`, otherwise use `%a`. (c) If x is the value in `float f`, and `%f` produces a numeral that, when converted to `float` using the current implementation’s rounding, use `%f`, otherwise use `%a`.

Comment: (d) If x is a numeral, and `f` is a `float` that results from the source text `f = x;`, and `%f` produces a numeral that is exactly x, use `%f`, otherwise use `%a`. Hint: Don’t pick (d); it is essentially impossible. Edit the question to state the criterion clearly and explicitly.

Comment: @user3386109: The fact that different implementations may have different behaviors is not a reason not to do what OP is attempting to do unless portability is their goal (not yours). OP has entered a campaign of questions showing they are engaging in some project which may well customize itself to various implementations, in which case lack of portability would not be a barrier.

Comment: @user3386109 I said "I understand about numbers like 1.225000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625", but we both goofed.  Not that it really matters at this point, but I believe that's a `double`.  I believe the `float` value you meant was 1.22500002384185791015625.

Comment: @pmor It occurs to me that your question shares a lot in common with the classic and frequently-asked "How can I print floating-point numbers with maximum precision in minimum space?", and that some of the answers at [Printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value) may therefore be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the condition for "the floating constant cannot be printed precisely using %f"?

This answer refers to the floating point object (e.g. `double`) defined by the FP constant, not the original source code text.

When the output text/*string* does not round trip back to the original `double`, string is not precise enough.

If OP does not want to try various *precsisons*, then try `"%f"` once.

```
void print_f(double x) {
  char buf[1000];
  for (int prec = 0; ; prec++) {
    int len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*f", prec, x);
    if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof buf) break; 
    double y = atof(buf);
    if (x == y) {
      puts(buf);
      return;
    }
  }
  printf("%a\n", x);
}
```

Above uses linear attempts.  Re-write could try 1,2,4,8,16,.... and then bisect to the minimum.

---

Alternative, [`printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839658/2410359) to get close to OP's goal, but with simpler code.

Comment: Do you think that it is possible to determine that w/o is_round_trip_back_to_the_original check? For example, by using somehow `frexp`.

Comment: @pmor Yes, possible to do w/o is_round_trip_back_to_the_original check.  Yet I see it as more work and error prone.  Why not use `printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, x);` instead of `"%f"`.  It is different, yet it always retains sufficient precision?

Comment: @pmor All finite `double` can be _exactly_ printed in decimal [somehow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).  Yet `printf()` may fail to print correctly past many significant digits - that is a quality of implementation issue.  Highly portable code should not rely on printing more than `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG (17)` significant digits correctly.  (I would not even count on more than `DBL_DIG (15)` significant digits correctly.)

Comment: @pmor More on printing with high significant precision: With `printf()` attempting to print `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant or more digits, lessor quality implementations may print only _about_ correct, just zeros, or even junk digits.  I’d still expect, even with errant output, the `atof()` of that string still result in a matching original `double` as there is a fair amount of tolerance to achieve round-trip in these least significant digits.

Comment: @pmor   What makes your question so awkward is preferring `"%f"`, rather than `"%e"`, `"%a"`, or `"%g"`.  `"%f"` takes the _floating_ out of presenting a `double` as it obliges a _fixed_ place decimal point.

Comment: Didn't get your last sentence (_"%f" takes the floating out of presenting a double as it obliges a fixed place decimal point._). Can you rephrase it?

Comment: @pmor (another good question)  Floating point numbers, for the most part, have _relative_ precision. With `"%f"`,  1.0e300 prints hundreds of uninformative digits past the first 15-20.  1e-10 prints as 0.000000, quite useless as nearly half of all `double` print the same value.  `"%f"` would make sense for a _fixed point_ type.